# Micronaut Hibernate Second Level Cache

Tags: hazelcast, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to enable Hibernate Second Level Cache with using of hazelcast in client server mode.
but when i run the application i get this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.hazelcast.client.cache.impl.HazelcastClientCachingProvider
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

this is my hibernate configuration

```
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_query_cache: false
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: com.hazelcast.client.cache.HazelcastClientCachingProvider
```

[Updated]
this is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "$micronautAppVersion"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "$googleJibVersion"
    id "jacoco"
}

version = "0.1"

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.test")
    }
}

dependencies {

    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation"
    annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi"
    implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
    implementation "io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa"
    implementation "io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    implementation('io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-hazelcast')
    runtimeOnly "io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari"
}
```

Comment: It simply means that your Hazelcast class is not in the classpath at runtime. Are you sure you declared the dependencies correctly? can you show your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

`HazelcastClientCachingProvider` is a client, it means it doesn't have any cache of its own and it can only communicate with another cache server (actually, it's recommended to use `jcache` as the standard Java caching API instead of provider-specific clients).

Micronaut does not automatically start a cache server by including the dependency. You're gonna have to configure it [like this](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-cache/snapshot/guide)

Alternatively, you can configure an embedded cache directly with hibernate configuration:

```
hibernate:
    cache:
      region:
        factory_class: jcache
    javax:
      cache:
        provider: com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider
        uri: <HazelcastConfig.xml>
```